# sum of top n values based on filtered criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set of the following order:

NIC Code|Firm Name|Year|Real NS

In column(A) represented by NIC code, I have around 70 *unique* numbers representing NIC codes, while correspondingly I have the name of the firm in column(B), Year in column(C) and Real NS in column (D).

Years 1990-2013; No. of Unique Firm- 10500

I want the sum of highest four values of real NS corresponding to an unique NIC and the year.

It is also to be noted that for each unique NIC code and years there might not be 4 entries, in such a case I would want to have the sum of all the values corresponding to the NIC code and the particular year.

Now, for the output starting from column E2 to E71 I have listed the unique NIC codes and from K1 I have put the years till AC1. In this space I want the sum of top 4 values.

I had initially used this code

```
=sumproduct(Large(A:A=E2)*(C:C=$k$1)*(D:D),{1,2,3,4})
```

in the cell K2 but it does not work out.

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version almost works, just need to get the syntax right, try this

`=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((A:A=$E2)*(C:C=K$1)*(D:D),{1,2,3,4}))`

...although it's better to restrict the ranges to a specific number of rows, otherwise the formula might be slow if you have multiple iterations of it.

The above won't handle negative values in the top 4 and also won't work if there is text anywhere in column D. This version will cope with negative values and also allow text in column D

`=SUM(IFERROR(LARGE(IF((A:A=$E2)*(C:C=K$1),D:D),{1,2,3,4}),0))`

needs to be "array entered" using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that curly braces appear around the formula in the formula bar.

Again, better to restrict the ranges rather than using the whole column

Comment: Thanks. There are both positive and negative values in column D. The syntax you mentioned does not work still. It gives me the error "VALUE!".

Comment: OK, that version works for me but won't work if you have text values anywhere in column D (even row 1 header), so you can either change the range to avoid that or use an "array formula" that can ignore that. I'll edt to that effect

Comment: Also, there are some missing values in column D. Which I can think can be taken care of by putting 0 instead of blank cells.There are no text values. Furthermore, as you mentioned earlier, I have specified the ranges which starts from row 2.

Comment: Text values will also include "null strings", so the cell might look empty but isn't. Try the array formula - that should always work as long as the values in column D are numbers

Comment: Thanks a lot. This "=SUM(IFERROR(LARGE(IF((A:A=$E2)*(C:C=K$1),D:D),{1,2,3,4}),0))" worked.